# Add new method to vuejs instance in child javascript

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent javascript P1.js with `parentVue` variable and a child javascript C1.js with `childVue` variable.

I want to add a new method to `parentVue` in `childVue` by somehow extending the `parentVue` . Can this be done?

```
var parentVue = new Vue({
    el: '#idAppointmentDetails',
    
    methods: {
        f1: function () {
            console.log('f1');
        },
    },
});

var childVue = Vue.extend({
    methods: {
        f2: function () {
            console.log('f2');
        },
    },
});
```

I wont know about f2 when I am building `parentVue` so I dont want to explore the option of adding mixin to `parentVue`.

Comment: why dont you use $refs

Comment: Not sure how. Can u provide an example please

Comment: Check this.   https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to add new method to parent Vue instance.

So I created a new component in child js:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";


Vue.component('notes-edit-comp', {
    props: ['appnt', 'updateapi'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            successUrl: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        saveNotesClicked: async function () {
            console.log('saveNotesClicked', this.updateapi);
            window.location.href = detailViewSuccessRedirectUrl;

        }
    },
    template: `
    <div id="idEditNotes" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="idNotes">Notes</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" v-model="appnt.notes"
                      style="max-width: 40rem;"
                      placeholder="xyz"
                      id="idNotes"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success"
                    v-on:click="saveNotesClicked()"
            >save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  `,
    delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
})
```